# Javascript's default event prevention not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events, preventdefault

I'm trying to redirect the 'My Profile' menu link to a custom url when the user's browser has Javascript enabled. I've already coded a custom url creating dynamic function `getNewURL()` and the concatenation works fine. The problem is that even when Javascript is enabled (on my Chrome), the default page in the href loads, despite all the default prevention code. I've been spending hours on this, and can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function init() {
    document.getElementById('profile').onclick=getNewURL;
}

window.onload=function(){
init();
}



function getNewURL(e)
{
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    var a = 'http://www.google.com/'; 
    var b = 'advanced_search?hl=en';//this will actually be a dynamic wikispaces
             //variable - the username. 
    var url = a+b;

    window.location.href = url;

    //Over-riding default action
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;

    //e.stopPropagation works only in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" id="profile">My Profile</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: your e.preventDefault is inside your check for e.stopPropagation. so when your not on firefox its not doing that. if you move it outside of the if statement it should work in chrome

Comment: I was hoping that was it, but sadly it's not. Default prevention still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see where you're invoking your `init` method.

Comment: I thought init() was inbuilt. My bad. Added this to the code to invoke it. window.onload=function(){init();}   Still going to the default page.

Comment: D'oh. forgot to save and try. Works now! Thanks everyone. You all collectively helped me fix it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I was just about to say that my testing showed it working fine. FYI, you can shorten the `window.onload` to this... `window.onload = init;` *(notice the function is being assigned, not  called)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is e?

```
function getNewURL()
{
    if(!e) var e = window.event;  <--
```

Should be

```
function getNewURL(e)
{
    if(!e) e = window.event;
```

Comment: Um, there was more than just the var

Comment: Thanks! works now. Your suggestion helped fix part of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you forgot to add parameter to function definition

```
function getNewURL(e) ...
```

Comment: Woops..typo. I had e in my actual definition. Still didn't work.